# Webkit text flickers when using CSS transform (scale)

Tags: html, css, browser, safari

This happens in Safari 6 on Mountain Lion and in the latest chrome. **(Confirmed on OSX, might not happen in windows)**

Please see this page for an example:

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/flicker2.html

Quickly move your mouse on and off the image and look at the text below. You will see it flickering/pulsing.

The associated CSS is below. I cannot make any changes to the `.out` and `.in` classes. Only to the item class.

I have tried adding `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` as I read somewhere that that should fix it, but it hasn't made any difference.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks,
Wesley

```
.out {                                      
   position:        relative;                                       
   display:        block;                                      
   margin:            0;                                      
   border:            0;
   padding:        0;                                      
   margin-left:    auto;                                       
   margin-right:    auto;                                      
   overflow:        hidden;    
 }
.in {                                   
   position:        relative;                                       
   display:        block;                                      
   margin:            0;                           
   padding:        0;                            
   border:            0;
   overflow:        hidden;
}
.item {
   margin: 60px;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s linear;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform .15s linear;
   -o-transition: -o-transform .15s linear;
   transition: transform .15s linear;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -o-transform-style : preserve-3d;
   -ms-transform-style : preserve-3d;
}
.item:hover {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) !important;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.3) !important;
   -o-transform: scale(1.3) !important;
   -ms-transform: scale(1.3) !important;
   transform: scale(1.3) !important;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine here in Chrome on Win7, have you tried using other browsers?

Comment: I Just tested via browserstack.com - and it appears that it only happens on Mountain Lion (osx)

Comment: Does it happen on all browsers in Mountain Lion? Or just Safari / all webkit based?

Comment: Actually I asked someone to test it themselves, and it happens in Lion too. Might just be OSX only. It doesn't happen in Firefox. Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware acceleration issue in Webkit. It may be worth using this as a test case and reporting the bug.

Comment: @PhonicUK - I think I found an existing bug report for this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23364 -- it's from 2009 and as yet unresolved.. If anyone knows a workaround I'd be very grateful because as it stands waiting for the Webkit folks to fix this might take another few years! Thx.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem: I want to scale an element on hover, and when doing so every text on the page flickers. I'm also on latest Chrome (21.0.1180.89) and OSX Mountain Lion.

Actually, adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
```

to the affected elements **does** solve the problem.

You said you can't change the .in and .out classes, but maybe you can add another one (.no-flicker) and use it on the affected elements.

*Note:* This really does seem to help fix the problem in Chrome, but Note it might cause some issues in Safari if you have elements layered with z positioning CSS properties. For instance, on my site it is causing a CSS element to flicker behind the slide transitions of the animated slide show I am trying to clean up.

Comment: thanks. I am surprised each time how fast (-I googled "chrome transition scale moves"-) such a vaguely appearing problems is solved in times of the community-web. Kudos to google as well.

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem, but fix it.

Just add the `.no-flickr` class to any blinking or flickering element in your project

```css
.no-flickr {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem this morning and found that the best fix was:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I added this to each of the two elements that make up the **faces** of the two sided object. Stopped the flicker in Chrome and fixed the backface showing in Safari.

Comment: -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; hid everything on my page. -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; indeed helped - but that was in previous answers. I find your answer confusing.

Comment: actually in my last project "preserve-3d" solved the -webkit- scrollbar from jumping around when I hovered over an inline-block element that had a on:hover scale (zoom-in) effect on the caption inside it..
My guess is that preserving the 3d helps retain the element's original bounds, especially when using a grid full of inline-block project cells all smushed next to each other...

Comment: working with perspectives and scales started flickering all my divs/li's with relative positions. adding preserve-3d to the parent container (the container where the transform and scales are) stopped this annoying flickering, ty